# Differential of a family of diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, diffeomorphism

Suppose one has a smooth curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to M$ on a manifold $M$ and a smooth one-parameter family $f_t:M\to M$ of diffeomorphisms (not necessarily a one-parameter subgroup). Then, the curve $\rho(t)=f_t(\gamma(t))$ is smooth.

My question is: is there a way to relate the velocity of $\gamma$ with the one of $\rho$? How may one derive $\frac{d}{dt}f_t(\gamma(t))$?

Comment: Do you know the Chain Rule?

Comment: So both $\rho(t)$ and $f_s(\gamma(t))$ have the same velocity at $t=s$?

Comment: I did not say this; in general, no. How would you have solved this in a vector calculus class, before you have learned about manifolds?

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it. So $\left.\frac{d}{dt}f_t(\gamma(t))\right|_{t=0}=\left.\frac{df_t}{dt}(f_0(\gamma(0)))\right|_{t=0}+df_0(\frac{d}{dt}\gamma\big|_{t=0})$, where denote $\frac{df_t}{dt}$ the vector field on $M$ induced by the family $f_t$?

Comment: Right..........